# Getting errors while running in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm having trouble running this code in python. This is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

stars_with_planet = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Stars\starswithplanet.csv')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(stars_with_planet)

    
stars_without_planet = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Stars\starswithoutplanet.csv')

df2 = pd.DataFrame(stars_without_planet)

df3 = df1.loc[(df1['TeffK'] >= 3500) & (df1['TeffK'] <= 5400)]
df4 = df2.loc[(df2['TeffK'] >= 3500) & (df2['TeffK'] <= 5400)]

df3['check'] = df3[['[Fe/H]']].apply(tuple, axis=1)\
              .isin(df4[['[Fe/H]']].apply(tuple, axis=1))
```

It is showing the following error after the last line:

> C:\Users\AG\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5940/3520898032.py:1:
> SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
> value instead See the caveats in the documentation:
> pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/… df3['check'] =
> df3[['[Fe/H]']].apply(tuple, axis=1)\

Please help me I have used Jupyter notebook.

The CSV Files are attached below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eDf2G969tdaxZrM9mQXk3mSKHrjABRUQ/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t8OZGgxaXbbp5X-9Ms8NJd4AZfYUMOGC/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The one you are showing at the line below is not en error:

```
df3['check'] = df3[['[Fe/H]']].apply(tuple, axis=1).isin(df4[['[Fe/H]']].apply(tuple, axis=1))
```

It's a warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:16: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

The pandas `SettingWithCopyWarning` warns you that you may be doing some chained assignments that may not work as expected.
Basically the issue is that modifications to your `df3` will not lead to modification to your original `df1`.

If you don't care about keeping `df1` updated, but you only care about `df3`, you could do this:

```
df3 = df1.loc[(df1['TeffK'] >= 3500) & (df1['TeffK'] <= 5400)].copy()
...
df3['check'] = df3[['[Fe/H]']].apply(tuple, axis=1).isin(df4[['[Fe/H]']].apply(tuple, axis=1))
```

Otherwise, you can do as suggested by the warning. I'm not entirely sure what your expected outcome is, but this code below updates directly `df1`:

```
df1.loc[(df1['TeffK'] >= 3500) & (df1['TeffK'] <= 5400), 'check'] = df1[['[Fe/H]']].apply(tuple, axis=1).isin(df4[['[Fe/H]']].apply(tuple, axis=1))
```

Comment: Any updates? Does this fixes your issue?